# Is it possbile to upper bound ${\bf tr}(ABC)$ by ${\bf tr}(AB)$ provided $A,B,C$ are all real, symmetric and positive definite?

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, matrix-analysis

Suppose $A,B,C$ are all real symmetric and positive definite matrices. Is it possible to lower bound ${\bf tr}(ABC)$ in terms of ${\bf tr}(AB)$.

I tried to follow Von Neumann's trace inequality: letting $\{a_i\}, \{c_i\}$ are the singular values in non-increasing order of $AB$ and $C$ respectively,
\begin{align*}
{\bf tr} (ABC) \le \sum_{i=1}^n a_i b_i \le \sum_{i=1}^n a_i \|C\|_2,
\end{align*}
as $a_i$'s are all nonnegative. However I could not relate the sum of $a_i$'s with ${\bf tr}(AB)$.

We can also do following:
\begin{align*}
{\bf tr} (ABC) \le \|BC\|_2{\bf tr} (A) \le \|B\|_2 \|C\|_2 {\bf tr}(A) \le \frac{\|B\|_2\|C\|_2} {\lambda_{\min}(B) } {\bf tr}(AB).
\end{align*}

I am in particular interested in a constant that is not determined by $B$.

Comment: I guess you mean in terms of $\operatorname{tr}AB$ and $\|C\|_2$? It is clearly not possible to have a bound that is independent of $C$.

Comment: @Rahul: Yes. I presume the constant should be related to some quantity of $C$.

Answer (score 1):

$\DeclareMathOperator{Tr}{Tr}$
Let
$$\begin{align}
D&=A^{1/2}BA^{1/2}\\
E&=\frac{A^{-1/2}CA^{1/2}+A^{1/2}CA^{-1/2}}{2}\text{.}
\end{align}$$
Then $D$ is positive definite, $E$ is symmetric (square roots of real p.d. matrices are real), and
$$\frac{\Tr ABC}{\Tr AB}=\frac{\Tr DE}{\Tr D}\leq \lambda_{\text{max}}(E)\text{,}$$
equality being approached as $D$ approaches the spectral projector for $\lambda_{\text{max}}(E)$. Therefore
$$\Tr ABC \leq \Tr AB\,\lambda_{\text{max}}\left(\tfrac{A^{-1/2}CA^{1/2}+A^{1/2}CA^{-1/2}}{2}\right)\text{.}$$

Note that $\lambda_{\text{max}}(E)$ is not bounded by $\lVert C\rVert_{\infty}$ independent of $A$. For example, let 
$$\begin{align}
A^{1/2}&=1+rX &
C&=1+sZ
\end{align}$$
where $X$ and $Z$ are Pauli matrices, $0<r<1$, and $0<s<1$. Then
$$E=1+\frac{s(1+r^2)}{1-r^2}Z$$
has unbounded spectrum as $r\to 1$.

Comment: I believe by $\lambda_{\max}(E)$ you really mean the largest singular value of $E$ as $E$ is only symmetric not psd. One question: could you comment how the singular value of $E$ relate to the eigenvalue of $C$?

Comment: I mean the maximum eigenvalue $\lambda_{\text{max}}(E)$ of $E$: what's important for the inequality is that $\lambda_{\text{max}}(E) - E$ is positive semidefinite.